# How do I access/read the Phonegap API?

Tags: api, cordova

I know there is this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/index.html but it doesn't really help.

I am trying to learn about the appView variable (I think it's a variable). I would've said it was a class but it starts with a lower case letter :/

The reason I am trying to learn that is because I am trying to understand the appView.addJavascriptInterface(Object, String) method.

My main goal is to send a variable from a java file to a javascript file. Tutorials online seem to be using the method stated above. Because the method takes in an object, the tutorials seem to be creating another class. I want to simplify my code as much as possible so I was seeing if there are any other options.

Answer (score 0):

In appView.addJavascriptInterface(Object, String)  method Object refers to Java object from which you want to transfer data from Java to java script.

You can't achieve functionality without creating new class.
Apart from Plugin usage above mentioned way only we can achieve communication between java and javascript in phonegap apps.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your response. I just decided to just go with creating another class.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to [write a Plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide). We've already gone through the pain of the JS to Java and back to JS communication. If you purely use addJavaScriptInterface you will run into some edge cases where it doesn't work and we already guard against.